# readfile doesn't force download

Tags: php, download, readfile

I'm trying to force a download when opening a page in php using readfile, but it doesn't work. When I go to the url https://www.inbrax.cl/belong-gracias/?docsbelong=BELONG-DICCIONARIO-CAP-1.pdf it displays the error message: 'El archivo no existe.', but if I console.log $fileName and $filePath it shows the correct information. It just doesn't execute the download.

I'm only starting to use php so I'm not sure what's the error.

I've tried adjusting the headers and changing the path but it hasn't worked yet.

Here's my code:

```
<?php
if(!empty($_GET['docsbelong'])){ 
    // Define file name and path 
    $fileName = basename($_GET['docsbelong']); 
    $filePath = './pdf/'.$fileName;  
 
    if(!empty($fileName) && file_exists($filePath)){ 
        // Define headers 
        header("Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0"); 
        header("Content-Description: File Transfer"); 
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$fileName\"");
        header("Content-Type: application/pdf"); 
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"); 
         
        // Read the file 
        readfile($fileName); 
        exit; 
    }else{ 
        echo 'El archivo no existe.';
    } 
} 
?>
```

Comment: *"it displays the error message: 'El archivo no existe.'"* - Then `!empty($fileName) && file_exists($filePath)` evaluates to `false`.  When you debug, what is the observed value of `$fileName`?  What is the full path of the file you're expecting it to read?  What is the current working directory when the code is executing?  (Hint: Absolute paths are almost always better than assumed relative paths in operations like this.  The server-side code should be configured to know which *folder* to find the file being requested, if all that's being requested is a file name.

Answer (score 0):

You just need the URL in a web page none of that non working code its superfluous eye candy to serving a download URL. You could add a static thumbnail of the cover as time better spent as just needing a second line of code.
[image]

```html
<a href="https://www.inbrax.cl/docsbelong/BELONG-DICCIONARIO-CAP-1.pdf" download="BELONG-DICCIONARIO-CAP-1.pdf">Click here to Download and View,<br>or rightclick to Save As Download<br>BELONG-DICCIONARIO-CAP-1</a>
```